# sql - Transform multiple columns (different data type) into one column (one row for column)

Tags: sql-server

I trying to transform multiple columns with different data type into one column (one row for column), all column would be cast to varchar.

My table to transform:

```
+----+----------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| id | column_varchar |     column_datetime     | column_int | column_bit |
+====+================+============+==========+===========+===========+===+
| 1  |      NULL      |           NULL          |     NULL   |     1      |
+----+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 2  |      NULL      | 2019-01-15 00:00:00.000 |     NULL   |    NULL    |
+----+----------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+  
| 3  |      apple     |           NULL          |     NULL   |    NULL    |
+----+----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---+
| 4  |      NULL      |           NULL          |     NULL   |     0      |
+----+----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---+
| 5  |      NULL      | 2018-01-15 00:00:00.000 |     NULL   |    NULL    |
+----+----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---+
| 6  |      NULL      |           NULL          |     25     |    NULL    |
+----+----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---+
```

i need create one single column that contains the value of all columns (cast to varchar) with its respective key value, I expect something like:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id |        column_value     |
+====+=========================+
|  1 |              1          |
+----+-------------------------+
|  2 | 2019-01-15 00:00:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
|  3 |           apple         |
+----+-------------------------+
|  4 |            0            |
+----+-------------------------+
|  5 | 2018-01-15 00:00:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
|  6 |           25            |
+----+-------------------------+
```

How can i accomplish this task with SQL-Server? thanks

Comment: Why 1 for Id 6? I think it should be 25.

Comment: @SurajKumar My mistake, I corrected it, thank you.

Comment: I think using COALESCE proposed by @ level3looper is the easiest option to implement

Comment: I think it is very interesting to use Cross Apply with xml proposed by @JohnCappelletti, but a bit more complicated than I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Coalesce:

```
Select id,coalesce
             (
               cv,
               Cast(cd As VarChar(50)),
               Cast(ci As VarChar(50)),
               Cast(cb As VarChar(50))
             ) As ColVal
From #tbl
```

Result:

```
id  ColVal
1   1
2   Jan 15 2019 12:00AM
3   Apple
4   0
5   Jan 15 2019 12:00AM
6   25
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using a bit of XML in concert with a CROSS APPLY (or two)

Other options may be more performant, but the beauty here is that it will consume virtually any table, view or query without having to specify the columns.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,C.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values (convert(xml,(Select A.* for XML RAW)))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) C
 Where Item not in ('ID')
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Item              Value
1   column_bit        1
2   column_datetime   2019-01-15T00:00:00
3   column_varchar    apple
4   column_bit        0
5   column_datetime   2019-01-15T00:00:00
6   column_int        25
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it:

```
SELECT
   id
  ,column_varchar  column_value  --  Column alias in only needs to be set in the first select
 from MyTable
 where column_varchar is not null
UNION ALL SELECT
   id
  ,convert(varchar(50), column_datetime, 121)
 from MyTable
 where column_datetime is not null
UNION ALL SELECT
   id
  ,cast(column_int as (varchar(50))
 from MyTable
 where column_int is not null
UNION ALL SELECT
   id
  ,cast(column_bit as (varchar(50))
 from MyTable
 where column_bit is not null
```

(Just to say, for a whole lot of reasons doing this is probably not a good idea.)

Comment: I assumed that multiple columns in a row might be NOT NULL. If this is not the case, then this solution is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If only **ONE** value per row, you can use `concat()`

You may notice that I did a convert on the datetime column to maintain the format.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,column_value = concat([column_varchar],convert(varchar(25),[column_datetime],25),[column_int],[column_bit])
 From  YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
1   1
2   2019-01-15 00:00:00.000
3   apple
4   0
5   2019-01-15 00:00:00.000
6   25
```

Comment: This will work if there is always one and only one NOT NULL column.

Comment: @PhilipKelley Thus my first line.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  The function concat() is very interesting, the problem occurs with the null values. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @bryannsi concat() will treat NULL values as an empty string ''